# How to attach a gas line to a gas fireplace when both ends are female flared?

Tags: natural-gas

Good Morning. Wondering if anyone can answer this. I bought this brass adaptor with the proper sized threads on both ends but only has a flare on the one end. I assume this won't work? The local fitting store recommended this black iron coupling but I can't figure out how this could work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That black coupling is a reducer.  I do not know how it would fit/work without a few more pieces/parts.  You probably want a male/male coupling with both ends flared.  Bring both pieces back and the picture of the pipes.  Look for an old person working there

Comment: Thank you crip659.  I'm glad I wasn't missing something.  I'll do just that.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a flare union (or coupling) fitting.

[image: flare union fitting]

<sub>Photo: acehardware.com</sub>

If you can't find that, you could use two flare-to-MIP like the one you had pictured, plus an FIP coupler.

Note that the copper tube appears kinked pretty badly in the U-bend. Have a closer look at that; it may be bad enough that you need to adjust your overall strategy about making this connection.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Greg.  Really appreciate it.